# IIF When Using Similar Criteria

Tags: ms-access, iif

Their are 2 different jobstatuses that I want to display the same way, my IIF statement changes the display, BUT I would like for only one entry to be returned for both.  For example, I want it to show like this

```
JobStatus
---------
Inactive
Let Go
```

But the returned result set I get is

```
JobStatus
---------
Active
Inactive
Let Go
Let Go
```

What do I need to change in my query to make it show like I need? (and I need this to be done via a query not vba)

```
jobstatus1: IIf([jobstatus]="Terminated","Let Go",IIf([jobstatus]="Fired","Let Go",[jobstatus]))
```

EDIT -- Full Syntax.  The IIF statement I need to use is for the `alpha.jobstatus` line right after the `Select`

```
SELECT alpha.jobstatus, Count(beta.ID) AS CountOfID
FROM alpha LEFT JOIN beta ON alpha.jobstatus = beta.jobstatus
GROUP BY alpha.jobstatus, alpha.order
HAVING (((alpha.jobstatus) Not In (Select [jobstatus] From tbl_Valid)))
ORDER BY alpha.order;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SELECT DISTINCT` to return only distinct values.

Also you can use a simpler expression for that calculated field --- one with a single `IIf` instead of nested `IIf`'s.  Switch your query to SQL View and revise the start of the statement text to this ...

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT IIf([jobstatus] IN ('Terminated', 'Fired'), 'Let Go', [jobstatus]) AS jobstatus1
```

Comment: I get an error of: You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression as part of an aggregate function

Comment: my apologies on that, I have posted full syntax now.

Comment: OK, first step: If you ignore the `HAVING` and `ORDER BY` for now, does this query run without error and return reasonable data? `SELECT IIf(alpha.jobstatus IN ('Terminated', 'Fired'), 'Let Go', alpha.jobstatus) AS jobstatus1, alpha.order, Count(beta.ID) AS CountOfID FROM alpha LEFT JOIN beta ON alpha.jobstatus = beta.jobstatus GROUP BY IIf(alpha.jobstatus IN ('Terminated', 'Fired'), 'Let Go', alpha.jobstatus), alpha.order`

Comment: Great!  I didn't understand your `HAVING` clause.  Hopefully this will work: `HAVING IIf(alpha.jobstatus IN ('Terminated', 'Fired'), 'Let Go', alpha.jobstatus) Not In (Select [jobstatus] From tbl_Valid)`  If so, then all you need to do is add the `ORDER BY`, which should be simple from Design View.